# How to count count the number of names Java

Tags: java, string, counter

Hi guys.
I'm new to Java, currently learning Strings.

I have a task to count the number of names, the length of the name must be at least two, the first letter of the name should start with upper case, the second with lower case.

The issue is that I don't know how to use the Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i)) and Character.isLowerCase(text.charAt(i + 1)) in the same if.

I would use some advice or hint.

```
class NameCounterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1
        System.out.println(new NameCounter().count("Mars is great planet"));

        // 2
        System.out.println(new NameCounter().count("Moon is near Earth"));

        // 0
        System.out.println(new NameCounter().count("SPACE IS GREAT"));
    }
}

class NameCounter {
    public int count(String text) {
        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        int wordLength = 0, counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String word = words[i];
            wordLength = word.length();

            if (wordLength >= 2 && Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i)))
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}

Output:
1; //Should be 1;
1; //Should be 2;
3; //Should be 0;
```

Comment: No, because I have many words and I have to loop over every word, unfortunately, I can't use a specified index @ATP

Comment: you can. after splitting the array for " " you know for sure that `word.charAt(0)` is the beginning of the word. work with `word` not with `text`, it was a mistake in the first comment also

Comment: Thanks, it helped, Character.isUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0), now I can access to every word of array, now I have to figure out how to use both Character.isUpperCase and Character.isLowerCase in the same if @ATP

Comment: use `&&` like you did for the `wordLength>2`.  you want all the 3  statements to be `true`. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `word.charAt(0)` and `word.charAt(1)` to get the first and second character in each word in the loop.

```
class NameCounterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1
        System.out.println(new NameCounter().count("Mars is great planet"));

        // 2
        System.out.println(new NameCounter().count("Moon is near Earth"));

        // 0
        System.out.println(new NameCounter().count("SPACE IS GREAT"));
    }
}

class NameCounter {
    public int count(String text) {
        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        int wordLength = 0, counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String word = words[i];
            wordLength = word.length();

            if (wordLength >= 2 && Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) && Character.isLowerCase(word.charAt(1)))
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just made it with if (wordLength >= 2 && Character.isUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) && Character.isLowerCase(words[i].charAt(1))), 
Anyway, I appreciate your help! Thanks :) @ATP

Comment: You're Welcome! BTW you already declared `words[i]` as `word` you can use `word` instead of `words[i]`